# Parsing LuisResult to get values field

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a LuisResult variable called result that has JSON info like

```
{
  "query": "what is twenty * three",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Multiplication",
    "score": 0.740870655
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Multiplication",
      "score": 0.740870655
    },
    {
      "intent": "Subtraction",
      "score": 0.04339512
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.0164503977
    },
    {
      "intent": "addition",
      "score": 0.0126439808
    },
    {
      "intent": "Division",
      "score": 0.0108866822
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "twenty",
      "type": "builtin.number",
      "startIndex": 8,
      "endIndex": 13,
      "resolution": {
        "value": "20"
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "three",
      "type": "builtin.number",
      "startIndex": 17,
      "endIndex": 21,
      "resolution": {
        "value": "3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to access the "value" field under "resolution" since it converts string representations of numbers to digit representation. At the moment I'm just trying to get the first value. I've tried to extract the value this way

```
    var valuesEntity = result.Entities;               //IList of all entities
    string s = "";
    s = valuesEntity[i].Resolution.Values.ToString(); //extract value field??
    await context.PostAsync($"{s}");                  //post to emulator
```

This prints out System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.String]

to me. What am I missing to be able to get the "values" field?

Comment: Resolution is a dictionary....and Values is a collection of strings..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
valuesEntity[i].Resolution.Values[0].ToString();
```

`Values` is a collection of strings.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I had to iterate through it like `foreach (var x in (v.Resolution.Values))`I wouldn't have been about to figure it out without you

Comment: I am getting "Cannot apply indexing with []  to an expression of type 'ICollection<object>'"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use linq and do:

```
valuesEntity[i].Resolution.Values.FirstOrDefault();
```